# How do I trigger a single event defined for a class of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question. I have 8 buttons that have unique incrementing id's and a shared class.

```
<button class="btnChapter" id="btnChapter_1" value="1">1</button>
<button class="btnChapter" id="btnChapter_2" value="2">2</button>
<button class="btnChapter" id="btnChapter_3" value="3">3</button>
...
```

In order to prevent me from duplicating code, I bound a click event to the btnChapter class instead of binding an event individually to each button's ID.

```
$('.btnChapter').click(function(){ .. do stuff .. });
```

How do I trigger() the click() event only for #btnChapter_2? The following doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#btnChapter_2').click()
```

Comment: and when you actually click the buttons, the event fires?

Comment: Please provide a pared-down test case that reproduces the problem (preferably at http://jsfiddle.net). As @JacobRelkin says, the code you have shown is sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine. Can you check whether the `click` event is actually binded to the `button` controls.

One reason I can think of is the code is the javascript is executed before the dom is ready, so the `$('.btnChapter')` selector may not return any element.

Can you check what is the value returned by `$('.btnChapter').length` soon after the click event is binded.

**Note: Can you manually click on the buttons and check whether the event is fired?**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QDA6t/) is a sample I did in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net), it works fine for me.

Comment: It does work. The "... do stuff ..."  portion was broken.  Next question:  How do I delete this post?  :-P

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine.

The only thing that you could possibly be doing wrong in my opinion is not executing this code after the `ready` event.

I'd also suggest the use of `live`.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.btnChapter').live('click', function(){ 
      //blah
  });
  //...
  $('#btnChapter_2').click();
});
```

Comment: if his markup won't changed or updated, don't you think that `live` is not needed then (performance-wise)?